# Leaflet freezes on zoom when it's in an XSLTForms XML file

Tags: leaflet, xsltforms

I'm working with XSLTForms and I need to add a Leaflet map. But something with that library doesn't work. I have the following code in a .xml file (as each xform I have) but when I zoom the map (by double click or click in the zoom button) it freezes.

The _zoomIn: function is still triggered when freezed but it doesn't make the expected visual changes.

This is the simple xforms example:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="xsltforms/xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<?xsltforms-options debug="no" lang="en"?>

<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
        xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
        xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="res/leaflet-0.8-dev/leaflet.css"/> 
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="res/style.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="res/jquery-ui/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="res/leaflet-0.8-dev/leaflet.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showOutdoorMap(id){
                var map = L.map(id);
                L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7'
                }).addTo(map);
                map.locate({setView: true});
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="showOutdoorMap('map')">
        <fieldset>
            <label class="header">Demo:</label>
            <div id="map" style='width:100%; height:250px;'/>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've seen your answer but for me it's working without any modifications: http://plnkr.co/edit/iZ32zKfB7wwvdxb56Xjg?p=preview What kind of errors were you getting? Only thing i did is modify the sources of the js/css assets

Comment: @iH8 that's because you have your index file as .html Try to change it as .xml

Comment: In fact, you are just seeing the HTML controls and not using the XSLTForms functionality. I just removed the XForms controls in order to make the example simpler, but you need to use it as here: http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms
That's why I have an .xml file

Comment: Oh, ok, didn't get that from your question. But at least with that plunker you know your HTML/JS is ok :) Kind of weird it doesn't work with your XML, i'm unable to test that now. Maybe if no apparent solution presents itself you could raise an issue over on their issuetracker: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues

Comment: @iH8 yep, I did it :) and I also posted the solution, just explained here for helping others with the same problem

Comment: Yes, i saw your solution, to me that's a hack. It should work without doing stuff like that but if you're ok with it, fine with me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was comment a line in the `setView: function (center, zoom, options)`, allowing the _resetView method to refresh:

```
if (animated) {
    clearTimeout(this._sizeTimer);
    /*return this;*/
}
```

I also had to comment this line in order to drag and drop with no problems:

```
/*if (L.DomUtil.hasClass(this._element, 'leaflet-zoom-anim')) { return; }*/
```